# How to configure GitLab CI Pipeline only on a specific branch and merge request event

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

On my gitlab CI yml, I want execute  my code only on the merge request and in the case of a specific branch.
I would like to lauch my treatment only if my branch starts with a number and the string   -release.
For example, 12-release

```
Test:
  except:
    - schedules
  only:
      refs:
        - /^[0-9]*-release/
        - merge_requests
  image: ubuntu
  before_script:
```

The pipeline starts whatever the branch name :'(

Thanks  for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) instead of `only`/`except` as the latter will be deprecated in the future.
Rewritten with rules your job will look like this:

```
Test:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^[0-9]*-release/'
  image: ubuntu
  before_script:
```